# Как передать в js правильный список?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть следующая разметка

```
<ul class="accordeon accordeon-desktop">...</ul>
<ul class="accordeon accordeon-mobile">...</ul>
```

И следующий js

```
function accordeonTeam() {
  const teamAccord = document.querySelector(".accordeon");
}
*описание функции*
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы js срабатывал и на втором списке?
1 список создан для отработки в десктопной версии, при разрешения 768 и меньше он скрывается и появляется 2, но его не видит код

Comment: Цикл по querySelectorAll

Comment: используйте `querySelectorAll` для выбора всех элементов по заданному фильтру. Для конвертирования в массив воспользуйтесь деструктуризацией `const items =  [...document.querySelectorAll(".accordeon")]`

Comment: вам бы в таком случае еще проверять. что список видимый.